# Using Gulp | Foundation 6 dropdown does not work

Tags: gulp, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Foundation dropdown errors out. It does not work.
Gives this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Feather' of undefined(…)
(anonymous function) @ foundation.js:1706
each @ foundation.js:77
each @ foundation.js:46
(anonymous     function) @ foundation.js:1705
each @ foundation.js:77
reflow @ foundation.js:1702
foundation @ foundation.js:1718
(anonymous function) @ results:271
```

I'm using gulp to put all the scripts together.

This problem shows when I include dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include foundation.util.nest.js in your build.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of each component you can see the dependencies. Be sure that you added them all.

For the dropdown menu, you can see at the end of the foundation.dropdownMenu.js file the following code:

```
/***/ 5:
/***/ (function(module, exports) {
          module.exports = {Keyboard: window.Foundation.Keyboard};
/***/ }),
/***/ 8:
/***/ (function(module, exports) {
          module.exports = {Box: window.Foundation.Box};
/***/ }),
/***/ 84:
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
          module.exports = __webpack_require__(18);
/***/ }),
/***/ 9:
/***/ (function(module, exports) {
          module.exports = {Nest: window.Foundation.Nest};
/***/ })
```

So, you have to add:

- foundation.util.nest.js,
- foundation.util.box.js,
- foundation.util.keyboard.js

and, of course, the

- foundation.dropdownMenu.js file.